# How do we initiate other actions after switching to the second screen in Python Kivy Screen Manager?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm giving an attempt at using the `ScreenManager` in Kivy.

To my expectation, the code below is supposed to accommodate two different screens: the first screen `ScreenOne` is a Play button and the second screen `ScreenTwo` is where the gameplay action is supposed to begin right away.

Problem is, I'm getting just an empty black screen when I switch to `ScreenTwo`.

```
# ---------- Original file: kivytut2.py  ----------

# Importations
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

# Creating my kv code in the Python file
Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0, 255, 255, .85
            on_press:
                # You can define the duration of the change
                # and the direction of the slide
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0.5
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
""")

# Create a class for all screens in which you can include
# helpful methods specific to that screen
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    # Detect collision, to comment out
    def collides(rect1, rect2):
        r1x = rect1[0][0]
        r1y = rect1[0][1]
        r2x = rect2[0][0]
        r2y = rect2[0][1]
        r1w = rect1[1][0]
        r1h = rect1[1][1]
        r2w = rect2[1][0]
        r2h = rect2[1][1]

        if (r1x < r2x + r2w and r1x + r1w > r2x and r1y < r2y + r2h and r1y + r1h > r2y):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def keyboard_events(self, **kwargs):
        super().keyboard_events(**kwargs)
        # Requesting keyboard event and setting its callbacks
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._on_keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_key_up)

        # The Fly rectangle
        with self.canvas:
            self.enemy = Rectangle(source="assets/theenemy.png", pos=(350, 350), size=(100, 85))
            self.player = Rectangle(source="assets/theplayer.png", pos=(150, 150), size=(100, 85))

        self.keysPressed = set()

        # Refresh frame every "second argument" seconds
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_step, 0)

    # Background musics
    sound = SoundLoader.load("assets/gp.wav")
    if sound:
        print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
        print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()

    # The keyboard callback when closed?
    def _on_keyboard_closed(self):
        self.keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)
        self.keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self.on_key_up)
        self.keyboard = None

    # The keyboard callback to change player position on key down
    def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.keysPressed.add(text)

    def _on_key_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        text = keycode[1]
        if text in self.keysPressed:
            self.keysPressed.remove(text)

    def move_step(self, dt):
        # Bottom left is origin, +x is right, -x is left, +y is up, -y is down
        currentx = self.player.pos[0]
        currenty = self.player.pos[1]

        # Move hundred pixels per second
        step_size = 100 * dt

        if "w" in self.keysPressed:
            currenty += step_size
        if "s" in self.keysPressed:
            currenty -= step_size
        if "a" in self.keysPressed:
            currentx -= step_size
        if "d" in self.keysPressed:
            currentx += step_size

        self.player.pos = (currentx, currenty)

        if collides((self.player.pos, self.player.size), (self.enemy.pos, self.player.size)):
            print("colliding, sire!")
        else:
            print("not colliding, sire.")


# The ScreenManager controls moving between screens
screen_manager = ScreenManager()

# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))

class KivyTut2App(App):

    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

sample_app = KivyTut2App()
sample_app.run()
```

In this, I'm using the Kivy Example file named `kivytut2.py` and also a tutorial from YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t1VXHICv-Q&t=388s

The whole idea is to use the `ScreenManager` in a very basic main menu.

I do appreciate every comment and directions to solve this one out! Cheers!

Comment: You haven't defined anything for `ScreenTwo` to display, so it does not display anything. Perhaps add a `<ScreenTwo>` rule to your `kv`.

Comment: You can also define an `on_enter()` method for your `ScreenTwo` class that will get executed every time to switch to that `Screen`.

Comment: Many thanks @John, I think you're right indeed. But.. erm.. how do we add the `<ScreenTwo>` rule again? Or would you care to elaborate how I can define the `on_enter()` method for the `ScreenTwo` class? I'm really new to coding so please accept my apologies ^^ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `<ScreenTwo>` rule just as you have done for `ScreenOne` in your `Builder.load_string()` call. Just add `<ScreenTwo>:` to the end of that string, and then define what you want to appear in `ScreenTwo` (as you have done for `ScreenOne`). Of course, that is only useful if you want something to appear in `ScreenTwo`.

I suggest that you start by adding an `on_enter()` method to `ScreenTwo` like:

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.keyboard_events()
```

This will be executed whenever you switch to `ScreenTwo` and it calls your `keyboard_events()` method of `ScreenTwo`. I think that will begin your game (after you fix some errors in that method).

Comment: Once again, thanks a lot @John Anderson. I'll add that to `<ScreenTwo>` and do my best to get things up and running. Feel free to provide any further clarification if you'd like!